# wp7 webbrowser control not navigating to a uri

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control

I am developing a wp7 app which involves twitter integration, For this i am using a webBrowser control to launch the twitter oauth verification.

launching the webBrowser shows a web page , asking user to login to their twitter account.
Everything is working fine except one thing.

there is a twitter signup button on the top right of the page.
If user taps on it, the web browser navigates to a blank screen and nothing happens. meanwhile other links in the webpage like "forgot password" works fine. webbrowser control navigates to twitter forgot web page.

However only on signup it is showing a blank screen, I am handling both the Navigating and navigated event of web browser. and this is the url that i get

```
https://mobile.twitter.com/signup
```

if i try the same url on the IE of wp7 phone it works fine!!!
confused why this is happening, Please let me know where i am going wrong. this is blocking me from my final app submission.

Answer (score 0):

Per default, Javascript is disabled in the WebBrowser control. Don't forget to activate it by setting `IsScriptEnabled` to True.

Comment: You can also try to provide a custom url in the oauth_callback parameter. Twitter should redirect to this url when authentication is successful.

Comment: yeah i am doing that , thats how i get the my access token and verification pin. but problem is not that, problem is if user taps on "signup" button (its not about "authorize button") , this is for sign up account in twitter. this button is located at top right corner of web page.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood. I don't know what could prevent the signup button from working. Have you tried setting the webbrowser control's address directly to https://mobile.twitter.com/signup to see if the page loads?

Comment: yeah if i set the webbrowser control's address directly to https://mobile.twitter.com/signup
it loads the page. But on signUp it doesnt work.. just shows a blank screen. I get navigating event but dont get the navigated event.

Comment: well after some more searching.. found out that its a problem with the webBrowser control itself.. there are a couple of other apps which are not able to shows twitter signup page